# Cant figure out data for psuedocode conversion in java

Tags: java

```
int month = 1;                                              
int balance = 500;                                              
int totalpaid = 0;                                              
double interest;                                                
  while (balance > 100);                                                
{                                               
  balance = balance - 100;                                              
  interest = (balance * 0.1);                                               
  balance = totalpaid + interest;                                               
  totalpaid = totalpaid + 100;                                              
  month = month + 1;                                                
}                                               
System.out.println ("you paid" + "," + totalpaid);                                              
System.out.println ("it took you" + "," + month + "months");
```

Im essentially trying to figure out the error in this code, the error is when I try to add the totalpaid and interest together.

Comment: First remove `;` from `while (balance > 100);`

Comment: I think you meant `balance = balance + interest;`

Comment: `balance` is an int, but you're adding `totalpaid` and `interest` which are `int` and `double` respectively. The answer is a `double` but its being rounded down, turning your answer into an `int`

Answer (score 2):

`balance` is an int, you are trying to add an `totalpaid` (int) and a `interest` (double) together. You can not do that, you must operate on the same data type. *Theoretically*, you could cast the result to an int and the error will be gone:

```
  balance = (int) totalpaid + interest;
```

But don't do that. Using `int` and `double` for working with currencies is not the correct way to go, as it is inaccurate and will potentially cause floating-point errors. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int month = 1;
        BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(500);
        BigDecimal totalpaid = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        BigDecimal interest;
        while (balance.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)) > 0)
        {
            balance = balance.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
            interest = (balance.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1)));
            balance =  (totalpaid.add(interest));
            totalpaid = totalpaid.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
            month = month + 1;
        }
        System.out.println ("you paid" + "," + totalpaid.toString());
        System.out.println ("it took you" + "," + month + "months");
    }
```

Comment: Actually you absolutely can add an `int` and a `double` together in Java.

Comment: @LewBloch if casting happens in the background. Try it yourself, define int a, int b and double c and try a = b + c. You will get incompatible types error. On the other hand, if a is declared double, it will not give error. This is because b automatically gets cast to a double during addition.

Comment: That isn't a failure to add the int and the double. That is a failure to assign a double to an int. The addition itself succeeded.